# JAVA Time Animation

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am trying to do a simple animation using Timer that adds and remove a button but i don't know where i am wrong. Also i added two prints just for verification. They print just right. Also i observed that if i remove the removeAll() method it adds the button .

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class Animation extends JPanel{
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tom1.png"));
    JLabel l2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tom2.png"));
    JLabel l3 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tom3.png"));
    JLabel l4 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tom4.png"));
    JLabel l5 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tom5.png"));
    JButton b1 = new JButton("HAHA");
    JButton b2 = new JButton();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public Animation(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Timer time = new Timer(1000,new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.out.println("paint");
                add(b1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                repaint();
                revalidate();
                System.out.println("remove");
                removeAll();
                repaint();
                revalidate();

            }
        });
        time.start();



    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new Animation());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(1000,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }



}
```

Comment: You're asking to add the button and then immediately you `removeAll()`. If the button shows up at all it'll be the barest flicker you'll never notice. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: What can i do then  ?

Comment: @zaa you want the button to flicker ?

Comment: You haven't said what you're trying to do. For all I know this is the desired behaviour; you just didn't notice. Are you trying to make the button show up and then disappear 1 second later?

Comment: @dcsohl yes ,thats what i want.

Comment: So I imagine you probably want to add the button **outside** of the Timer, and keep the removal inside. Then the add happens at constructor time, and the removal happens when the Timer goes off 1 second later. As a suggestion, you probably want to use [`remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#remove%28java.awt.Component%29) instead of `removeAll()` so that you can have other items present that don't disappear too.

Comment: Timer is like a loop, on each iteration, you need to do something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said in the comments, you are adding the button then removing **really** shortly after...

To make the button apprear one second and dissapear the other, you could make a flag , and do one thing one time in the timer , then do the other.
you could do this:

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Animation extends JPanel {
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tom1.png"));
    JLabel l2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tom2.png"));
    JLabel l3 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tom3.png"));
    JLabel l4 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tom4.png"));
    JLabel l5 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tom5.png"));
    JButton b1 = new JButton("HAHA");
    JButton b2 = new JButton();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    boolean isthere = false;

    public Animation() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Timer time = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (!isthere) {
                    System.out.println("paint");
                    add(b1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    repaint();
                    revalidate();

                    isthere = !isthere;
                } else {

                    System.out.println("remove");
                    removeAll();
                    repaint();
                    revalidate();
                    isthere = !isthere;
                }

            }
        });
        time.start();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new Animation());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(1000, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}
```

Comment: Or check the "parent" property of the button. It's also better to revalidate the container first, then repaint it

Comment: How can i stop it ? if i put time.stop() inside one of the loops it says time may not have been initialized.